# Django admin with TinyMCE and stacked inline renders Textarea with Visibility:Hidden

Tags: django, django-tinymce

I am using django-tinymce for my admin.

I've got a Category model with a Product model in a One-to-Many relationship.

In the app, I used StackedInline for Products and then added it to CategoryAdmin as such:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductInline]

     class Media:
         js = ('/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', '/static/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js',)
```

What happens is that in the Admin back-end, all the text areas are rendered with "Visibility: hidden" as such:

```
<textarea class="vLargeTextField" cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Anyone had a similar problem and with a resolution?

django 1.5, tinymce 1.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok #fml, I am stupid.

When I did:

```
class Media:
    js = ('/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js etc....
```

I did not realise that the tinymce app did not have a 'js' directory, so it should have been:

```
class Media:
    js = ('/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', '/static/tiny_mce/textareas.js')
```